# VS Code doesnt create new file when shortcut is used

Tags: visual-studio-code

This problem has been bothering me for quite a while. I use Atom Keymap extension and have create new file bind to A and create new folder to shift+A. However, after some time VS Code stops creating new files/folders and instead starts searching for a file. I am not sure if I press something to enable search instead, but the only thing that seems to help is restarting VS Code.[image]

Any ideas how to fix this behaviour?

Edit: These are the shortcuts for A and shift+A

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> "However, after some time VS Code stops creating new files/folders and
> instead starts searching for a file"

Did you clean up the VSCode cache and temp folders?

If not, try clean it:
Press window key and type

- `%temp%`
- `%appdata%`

Comment: I'll do that and see if it fixes the issue. As I mentioned, restarting VS Code helps to solve it, but the behaviour comes back after some time.

Comment: If so, then that's right. You should regularly clean up the files in these folders

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the file search feature, you can prevent this by disabling it in `settings.json`:

```json
"workbench.list.automaticKeyboardNavigation": false
```